# Java - напечатать пирамиду в консоли

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно напечатать вот так пирамиду.
Как сделать, чтобы она вот так была "отцентрована" по правому краю? 
Пробелами?
Размер пирамиды задается с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n = 8; //зададите с клавиатуры
for(int t=2;t<=n;t++)
  System.out.printf("%"+n+"s%n", new String(new char[t]).replace("\0", "x"));
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Да, так понятней. Это не задание ученика, т.к. я занимаюсь самообучением.

Comment: А в данном примере возможно вместо определенного количества пробелов вставить переменную?

Comment: Конечно можно, это же строка, можете её конструировать по своему усмотрению. Так же можно решить без форматирования, добавлением нужного кол-ва пробелов вначале. Можно через StringBuffer создать строку 1раз, потом на каждом шаге менять последний пробел на #. В общем вариантов множество.

Comment: Когда занимаетесь самообучением тоже можно описать проблему. "Пробовал так, так и так. Получаю такую-то ошибку... Или не тот результат, что ожидался." чем больше пробуешь сам, тем больше отложится

Comment: Не могу найти. Везде примеры, если количество символов, если говорим о %s и %d, или количество символов после запятой, если говорим о %f, задано изначально. А как задать через переменную количество символов? К примеру для %s должно быть int x символов.

Comment: @user249094, обновил ответ

Comment: Отлично. "%"+n+"s%n" - это то, что и искал. Спасибо!